# Tkinter how to make a calculator function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The global varible f_num is apparently not defined, even though i set global before it in `get_value()`. In addition `value_var` and `unit_set` seems to not be defined aswell. Why? I am trying to make a calculator that does an operation i select from `OPTIONS` and gives a correct answer based on what unit i want to input into `entry_value`. The units you choose from are `OPTIONS_UNITS`. So if i choose "energy" and "nm", the program want me to enter wavelength in nm (i have coded that in), and theoretically spits the correct answer based on my input in to `entry_value`, the `OPTIONS` i chose and the `OPTIONS_UNITS` i chose. To clarify some more: the only part i can't figure out is how to make a function that checks those conditions then if i press `button`, it computes everything and sends the answer to `label`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 900

h = 6.63e-34
c = 3.00e+8

def on_select(value):
    if value == OPTIONS[0]:
        label_enter_what['text'] = 'Enter wavelength in chosen unit below'
        label_unit['text'] = 'Enter what unit \n of wavelength'
        unit_set.set(OPTIONS_UNITS[1])
    elif value == OPTIONS[1]:
        label_enter_what['text'] = 'Enter wavelength in chosen unit below'
        label_unit['text'] = 'Enter what unit \n of wavelength'
        unit_set.set(OPTIONS_UNITS[1])
    elif value == OPTIONS[2]:
        label_enter_what['text'] = 'Enter energy in chosen unit below'
        label_unit['text'] = 'Enter what unit of energy'
        unit_set.set(OPTIONS_UNITS[3])


root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Photon property calculator")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('interference.jpg'))
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#3E3E3E', bd=5)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.75, anchor='n')

entry_value = tk.Entry(frame, font=40, bg='white')
entry_value.place(relx=0.175, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=0.4)

frame_upper = tk.Frame(root, bg='#3E3E3E', bd=2.5)
frame_upper.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.03, relheight=0.06, relwidth=0.75, anchor='n')

label_what_to_calc = tk.Label(frame_upper, bg='white', text='Enter what \n to calculate')
label_what_to_calc.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=0.15)

label_enter_what = tk.Label(frame_upper, bg='white', text='Select an option')
label_enter_what.place(relx=0.175, relheight=1, relwidth=0.4)

label_unit = tk.Label(frame_upper, bg='white', text='Enter what unit \n of wavelength')
label_unit.place(relx=0.6, relheight=1, relwidth=0.21)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#60A8FF', bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, relheight=0.5, relwidth=0.75, anchor='n')

OPTIONS = [
    "Energy",
    "Frequency",
    "Wavelength"
]

value_var = tk.StringVar(value=OPTIONS[0])

drop = tk.OptionMenu(frame, value_var, *OPTIONS, command=on_select)
drop.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=0.15)

OPTIONS_UNITS = ["μm",
                 "nm",
                 "pm",
                 "aJ",
                 "zJ",

]

unit_set = tk.StringVar(value=OPTIONS_UNITS[0])

drop_units = tk.OptionMenu(frame, unit_set, *OPTIONS_UNITS)
drop_units.place(relx=0.6, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=0.09)


def do_operation(f_num):
    if value_var.get() == OPTIONS_UNITS[0] and unit_set.get() == OPTIONS_UNITS[0]:
        new_num = f_num*10e-28
        return h*c/new_num


def get_value():
    first_number = entry_value.get()
    global f_num
    f_num = float(first_number)
    entry_value.delete(0, END)


print(do_operation(f_num))

button = tk.Button(frame, text='Calculate!', font=40, bg="#F96612", fg='black', command=lambda: do_operation(f_num))
button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

label = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='white', text='1')
label.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using `global varname` does not declare or initialize your variable. It merely tells the interpreter to look in the global scope whenever you use it. It still has to be defined before use. Consider a `class` based approach which avoids the need of global variables and is a lot simpler in terms of control flow. This is a great tutorial: https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html

Comment: Is this the only solution?